encrypt the filesystem of non-encrypted drive with luks
I have a partition non-encrypted. It has files and is ext4. Is it possible to encrypt it? First it will require map to luks name. For that the cryptsetup command informs current ext4 will be erased. Without map  to name, it may not be possible to encrypt. Coomand sequence is map to name, then luksFormat and then filesystem has to be created on active name after map. In this, there is no option to figure out if current drive is with filesystem and to convert it to luks because cryptsetup open deletes the ext4 signature on non encrypted drive. How can we encrypt without loss of data and filesystem or is it not supported? I have ubuntu 22.04 and when installed, I had root encrypted.

since back up of files and format it for encryption means what i asked is not supported for luks. It is boot partition. If it is system or only data does not matter if luks support plain partitions with filesystem to be encrypted. However, it is boot partition and not in use. I created it to grub-install on it with 2.12 and copy it to encrypted partition.

I do not have definite answer if luks encryption for non encrypted drive with filesystem is supported or not. My question would be if it is supported, how can we do it. though I find it difficult to believe that it is not  supported, hence this question post.
